# How I can send json map object from flask and use it as javascript object?

Tags: javascript, python, json

flask script

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
import os
import sys
import json


data_raw = [('0', '1', '0', '0'), ('0', '0', '1', '0'), ('1', '0', '0', '0')]
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('test.html', data=map(json.dumps, data_raw))
```

html/js script test.html

```
{% extends "index.html" %}
{% block content %}

<p id="test">info</p>

<script>
var data_flask = {{ data }};
</script>

{% endblock %}
```

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token &

The aim is store data_flask like this

```
var data_flask = [["0", "1", "0", "0"],["0", "0", "1", "0"],["1", "0", "0", "0"]]
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Flask, like Django, autoescapes values by default. You need to use the `|safe` filter to render the literal values.

```
var data_flask = {{ data|safe }};
```

Comment: >No I get thiss error Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

Comment: Well I also don't know why you're calling `map`. Why not just `data=json.dumps(data_raw)`?

Answer (score 0):

you should do `map(json.dump, data_raw)` and it should work instead of `map(json.dumps, data_raw)`